# c# - Digitally signinging a file

Tags: c#, csv, console-application

I am generating a csv file for a client and it has to be digitally signed. I have no previous experience with this process and very little knowledge of it.

I've received a public and private key as two files with '.ASC' extension.

I've spent the last few hours looking for a solution, but am unable to find something that fits my scenario.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If the client doesn't tell you *how* they expect the file to be signed, go back to them and ask them about it. I'm not talking about the code to sign it that way, I'm talking about what kind of signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.ASC` file looks like key for [GPG](https://www.gnupg.org/download/). To sign a file you need to import your private key into your private key ring. To do that

```
gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import private.asc
```

After that

```
gpg --output file.txt.sig --sign file.txt
```

You will be asked to enter your passphrase to unlock the private key which is used for signing the document. Signed content will be placed into `file.txt.gpg`.

If you need to use `GPG` with C# check the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787398/pgp-library-for-c) questions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I went through the topic you linked regarding GPG implementation in C#, but I am still unable to find what I am looking for. I found a **OpenPGP Library for .NET** which provides super simple way to sign a file: `pgp.SignFile(@"C:\INPUT.txt",
                @"C:\private_key.asc",
                "private key passphrase",
                @"C:\OUTPUT.pgp",
                asciiArmor);` but unfortunately is quiet costly. I am looking for something equally simple, yet free.

Comment: Update: I was finally able to complete my task with **GpgAPI** from _CodePlex_. It's quite simple, although their docummentation is rather useless and it took some time to figure out how to use it.